# Solving the 2D heat equation

Tags: differential-equations, regions, finite-element-method, heat-equation

I am trying to solve the 2D heat equation (or diffusion equation) in a disk:

```
NDSolve[{\!\(
    \*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(f[x, y, t]\)\) == \!\(
    \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\), \(2\)]\(f[x, y, t]\)\), 
      f[x, y, 0] == E^(-x^2 - y^2)}, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]
```

but I get this error

```
NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {f[x,y,0],f[x,y,t],(f^(0,0,1))[x,y,t]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined.
```

I want to include the Neumann boundary condition such that the normal derivative is zero. How can I include that?

edit: user21 fixed my mistake, here is a density plot from the code

```
DensityPlot3D[f[x, y, t] /. sol, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

with sol the solution as found below.

[image]

Comment: Please, post the code of the 3D plot

Comment: done, see edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the dependent variable `f` like so:

```
NDSolve[{Derivative[0, 0, 1][f][x, y, t] == 
   Derivative[0, 2, 0][f][x, y, t] + Derivative[2, 0, 0][f][x, y, t], 
  f[x, y, 0] == E^(-x^2 - y^2)}, f, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Element[{x, y}, Disk[{0, 0}]]]
```

Concerning the Neumann zero boundary condition: Neumann zero boundary conditions are the default so nothing needs to be done.

Comment: yes... I should have done that.. Thanks user21!  Also thanks for the info andre!

Comment: @andre, thanks added your comment to the post.