# Solving a system of temporal non-linear (reaction-diffusion) PDEs over a region using Neumann conditions

Tags: differential-equations, regions, nonlinear, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve a system of PDEs with non-linear terms:

$\frac{\partial a(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{-\text{$\tau_2 $ } a(x,y,z,t)  h(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_1 $ } d(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial b(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{-\text{$\tau_2 $ } b(x,y,z,t) i(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_1$ } e(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial c(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{-\text{$\tau_2 $ } c(x,y,z,t) g(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_1$ } f(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial d(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{\text{$\tau_2 $ } a(x,y,z,t) h(x,y,z,t)}-\text{$\tau_1 $ } d(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial e(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{\text{$\tau_2 $ } b(x,y,z,t) i(x,y,z,t)}-\text{$\tau_1 $ } e(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial f(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{red}{\text{$\tau_2 $ } c(x,y,z,t) g(x,y,z,t)}-\text{$\tau_1 $ } f(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial g(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{blue}{\mathscr{D} \nabla _{\{x,y,z\}}^{}g(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_3$ } a(x,y,z,t)-\frac{g(x,y,z,t)}{\text{$\tau $4 }}+\text{$\tau_1 $ } f(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial h(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{blue}{\mathscr{D} \nabla _{\{x,y,z\}}^{}h(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_3$ } b(x,y,z,t)-\frac{h(x,y,z,t)}{\text{$\tau $4 }}+\text{$\tau_1 $ } d(x,y,z,t)
\\\frac{\partial i(x,y,z,t)}{\partial t}=\color{blue}{\mathscr{D} \nabla _{\{x,y,z\}}^{}i(x,y,z,t)}+\text{$\tau_3 $ } c(x,y,z,t)-\frac{i(x,y,z,t)}{\text{$\tau $4 }}+\text{$\tau_1 $ } e(x,y,z,t)$

with non-linear terms in $\color{red}{red}$ and spatial terms in $\color{blue}{blue}$

i.e.

```
pdes = {
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][a][x, y, z, t] == 0.05*d[x, y, z, t] - 0.05*a[x, y, z, t]*h[x, y, z, t],
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][b][x, y, z, t] == 0.05*e[x, y, z, t] - 0.05*b[x, y, z, t]*i[x, y, z, t], 
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][c][x, y, z, t] == 0.05*f[x, y, z, t] - 0.05*c[x, y, z, t]*g[x, y, z, t], 
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][d][x, y, z, t] == -0.05*d[x, y, z, t] + 0.05*a[x, y, z, t]*h[x, y, z, t], 
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][e][x, y, z, t] == -0.05*e[x, y, z, t] + 0.05*b[x, y, z, t]*i[x, y, z, t], 
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][f][x, y, z, t] == -0.05*f[x, y, z, t] + 0.05*c[x, y, z, t]*g[x, y, z, t], 
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][g][x, y, z, t] == 100*a[x, y, z, t] + 0.05*f[x, y, z, t] + 
     0.05*(Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][g][x, y, z, t] + Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][g][x, y, z, t] + Derivative[2, 0, 0, 0][g][x, y, z, t]), 
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][h][x, y, z, t] == 100*b[x, y, z, t] + 0.05*d[x, y, z, t] + 
     0.05*(Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][h][x, y, z, t] + Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][h][x, y, z, t] + Derivative[2, 0, 0, 0][h][x, y, z, t]), 
Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][i][x, y, z, t] == 100*c[x, y, z, t] + 0.05*e[x, y, z, t]  + 
     0.05*(Derivative[0, 0, 2, 0][i][x, y, z, t] + Derivative[0, 2, 0, 0][i][x, y, z, t] + Derivative[2, 0, 0, 0][i][x, y, z, t])
};
```

with the following intitial conditions:

```
initcs = {
a[x, y, z, 0] == (Sqrt[40/Pi])/
     E^(40*((0.5 + x)^2 + y^2 + z^2)), 
b[x, y, z, 0] == (Sqrt[40/Pi])/E^(40*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)), 
c[x, y, z, 0] == (Sqrt[40/Pi])/E^(40*((-0.5 + x)^2 + y^2 + z^2)),
d[x, y, z, 0] == 0, e[x, y, z, 0] == 0, f[x, y, z, 0] == 0, 
g[x, y, z, 0] == 0, h[x, y, z, 0] == 0, i[x, y, z, 0] == 0
};
```

if I solve this in a cubic region I **DO** get an answer (although it tells me that the step-size might be too large):

```
sol = NDSolve[
  Flatten[{pdes, initcs}], {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, {x, -1, 
   1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

to plot:

```
    Export["disks.gif", 
 ListDensityPlot3D /@ 
  Transpose[sol[[1, 9, 2]]["ValuesOnGrid"], {2, 3, 4, 1}]]
```

[image]

However, I want to solve it in a specific region (a complex curved region). Lets take a cuboid region as an example since it should give the exact same solution:

```
 sol2 = NDSolve[
  Flatten[{pdes, initcs}], {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, 
   i}, {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], {t, 0, 
   1}]
```

this gives me an error, even though it is the exact same problem

```
NDSolve::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve.
```

Why does the second method not work when the second one does? How can I solve my problem?

**Edit:**
I have been suggested to look at the amazing answer of [user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19351/1871) to solving  the naiver-stokes equation. This seems like the right way to start, but this solves the steady state instead of the here required time-resolved solution.

After [linearizion (see chapter 4 and 5)](https://www.freidok.uni-freiburg.de/fedora/objects/freidok:6440/datastreams/FILE1/content)   I come to:

```
alfabet = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
coords = {x, y, z};
rulefunct = # -> #[x, y, z] & /@ alfabet;
alfabet2 = alfabet /. rulefunct;
F = { #} & /@ -{a*h - τ1 d, b*i - τ1 e, 
   c*g - τ1 f, -a*h + τ1 d, -b*i + τ1 e, -c*
     g + τ1 f, τ3*g, τ3 h, τ3 i} /. 
rulefunct /. {τ1 -> 1, τ3 -> 1};
A = Table[-D[F[[α]], alfabet2[[β]]], {α, 9}, {β,9}];
σ = -Normal[SparseArray[Table[{i, i, j, j} -> - d, {i, 7, 9}, {j, 1, 3}] // Flatten[# , 1] &]];
Γ =  Join[ ConstantArray[0, {6, 3}],Table[-d D[alfabet2[[α]],coords[[β]]], {α, 7,9}, {β, 3}]];
τ = IdentityMatrix[9]
```

to implement in:

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[Ball[]];
vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables", "Space"} -> {alfabet,
      coords}];
sd = NDSolve`SolutionData["Space" -> nr];
nlPdeCoeff = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, "LoadCoefficients" ->(*F*)F,
 "LoadDerivativeCoefficients" ->(*gamma*)Γ,
 "ReactionCoefficients" ->(*a*)A,
 "DampingCoefficients" -> IdentityMatrix[9],
 "DiffusionCoefficients" -> σ]
```

I do not yet see a way to give the right initial conditions(and initialize a 4D region?) such that the coeficients can indeed be scalar given I require the temporal solution.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, `FEM` still doesn't support `Nonlinear coefficients`.

Comment: @zhk What causes these coefficients to be different?

Comment: @zhk I believe both cases have non-linear system. In the first case it is solved, In the second it is not. Why?

Comment: In `sol1` `NDSolve` doesn't use `FEM` but by default uses `MOL` that's why it solve the system with some warnings.

Comment: @zhk Thanks for showing me the difference. Can I use the `MOL` to solve this problem? When I set `Method -> "MethodOfLines"` the problem is not solved

Comment: Or is the method of lines unavailable for arbitrary shapes?

Comment: It seems that you have errors in the forms of equations Nr. 3 and 6. Please have a look. In the place of Eq. Nr. 6 should stay the one for the function `f[x,y,z,t]` I guess, but I cannot interpret the expression staying there. Further, you need to fix boundary conditions. For the MethodOfLines I recommend to use the periodic ones if appropriate. After that your equations have a good chance to be solvable.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Thank you for your comment. I do not see what you mean with the errors in eq3 and 6, but that could be me.. Note that the problem is solved when the region is differently specified (i.e.`sol` works, `sol2` does not) . I do need the default Neumann conditions instead of periodic conditions.

Comment: @Ruud3.1415 Today I do not see these errors any more. Probably you have fixed them. However, the boundary conditions should be introduced anyway. It is known that the MethodOfLines sometimes is able to solve the system even with wrong boundary conditions, and that is what probably happened in your  case. However, I would not leave them unspecified.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I did not change anything in the PDEs but I know when ones stares other ones code, these things happen. On the boundary conditions, I was told here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149431/solving-the-2d-heat-equation that that should not give any problems since mathematically automatically assumes the right Neumann conditions

Comment: "Or is the method of lines unavailable for arbitrary shapes?" No, it's `"TensorProductGrid"` method that is unavailable for arbitrary shapes. `"TensorProductGrid"` and `"FiniteElement"` can both be used for spatial discretization of `"MethodOfLines"`, the former can handle nonlinear coefficient but can't handle irregular domain, while the latter can 
 handle irregular domain but cannot handle nonlinear coefficient (at least now). [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69646/1871) is a related post.

Comment: If you want to solve nonlinear PDE in irregular domain, then some relatively low level programming is needed. There already exist several examples in this site. You can start from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96579/1871).

Comment: @xzczd that does seem similar to what I want and a pretty nice problem to work on. However, I get a similar error when I implement my problem in that code: `NDSolve` backtick  `ProcessEquations::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve.`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm still in v9 so never play with those low level FEM functions, but according to my understanding for user21's code, this error should not appear if his method is correctly implemented. You can consider adding your updated code to the body of your question, maybe someone being familiar with low level FEM programming will come and have a look.

Comment: BTW, if low-level FEM programming is too hard, there exists another possible method, which is not that accurate but maybe acceptable: please check [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19351/1871).

Comment: @xzczd you are right, I was thrown off by the linearly defined "stokes" PDEs

Comment: Start with a simpler PDE. 1) stationary 1D. 2) Add the time still 1D. 3) Add the other dimensions. As a side question what does these equations model?

Comment: @user21, I am trying to moddel the spatial influences of the "repressilator" (a synthetically engineered oscillator in simple organisms (e.g. E.Coli). 1D is something worth trying indeed (I'm not sure about the steady state though, without initial conditions there are infinite solutions I think). What do you think, my plan is to make a 2D mesh in that case (1D for space and 1D for time) and use `DirichletCondition` for `t=0`. would the time dimension be included in `{"DependentVariables", "Space"}->`?

Comment: @Ruud3.1415, in that case I'd start with a 1D space and 1D time PDE. Do you have an example for which you have a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In version 12.0 you can do this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[Cuboid[{-1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, 1}], 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
sol = NDSolve[Flatten[{pdes, initcs}], {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, 
    Element[{x, y, z}, mesh], {t, 0, 1}][[1]];
fun = i[x, y, z, t] /. sol;
DensityPlot3D[Evaluate[fun /. t -> 1], {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh]
```

[image]